# SQL to return zero for records not found

Tags: sql

I have a chart that I want to display resources name and number of requests they are working on for each status type.  e.g. John Smith has 5 - in progress, 4 - not started, 5 - analysis, 0 - on Hold.

My query pulls all records for John Smith but only shows records that exist.  How do I force the result table to show the zero for John Smith that is on hold?

The results I want to show are 10 staff, with each staff showing all my status that are available (Not started, In Progress, On Hold, Analysis, Deferred etc.) and zero if no projects are in a particular phase for that resource.

Below image shows resource on far left but if some don't have a particular status it doesn't show. I want all status to show even if it is zero.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWhC0.png)

Comment: Please tag your DBMS

Comment: What is your table structure?

Comment: Edit your question and show the query that you are currently using, as well as sample data and desired results.  Tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Use left outer join and group the result.You will get Null if no record exists against 'John Smith'.

Try case when to convert null to zero.

Answer (score 0):

As a concept, produce a list of all staff and available statuses, then left join the data to this. This will provide a row for each, even if it does not exist for that member of staff.

SQL server / oracle

```
with staff as
(
select staffname, status
from (select distinct staffname from table1)
cross join (select distinct status from table1)
)
select staff.*, table1.OtherColumns
from staff
left join table1
  on staff.staffname = table2.staffname
  and staff.status = table2.status
```

MySQL:

```
select staff.*, table1.OtherColumns
from 
  (
  select staffname, status
  from (select distinct staffname from table1)
  cross join (select distinct status from table1)
  ) staff
left join table1
  on staff.staffname = table2.staffname
  and staff.status = table2.status
```